# jQuery Ajax request via proxy 404'ing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, proxy

I'm having some problems running a jQuery Ajax request through a proxy but I'm not sure what the problem is.

I have the following index.php code:

```
<div id="container">:(</div>

<form action="proxy.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="address"
        value="http://www.bungie.net/Platform/Destiny/2/Account/4611686018433330092/" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/destiny.js"></script>
```

This runs a short piece of jQuery (js/destiny.js):

```
$.ajax({
url: 'proxy.php',
type: 'POST',
dataType: "json",
data: {
    address: '/Platform/Destiny/2/Account/4611686018433330092/'
},
success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    // response now contains full HTML of google.com
    $("#container").html(':D');
},
error: function(req, status, errThrown){
    // error handling
    console.log("req: " + req);
    console.log("status: " + status);
    console.log("errThrown: " + errThrown);
}
```

});

My proxy.php is just the Google code PHP proxy, with the print line amended:

```
    <?php
/*
 * Author - Rob Thomson <rob@marotori.com>
 *
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License version 2 as
 * published by the Free Software Foundation.
 *
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 */

session_start();
ob_start();

ini_set('display_errors', 0);

/* config settings */
$base = "http://www.bungie.net";  //set this to the url you want to scrape
$ckfile = 'tmp/simpleproxy-cookie-'.session_id();  //this can be set to anywhere you fancy!  just make sure it is secure.

/* all system code happens below - you should not need to edit it! */

//work out cookie domain
$cookiedomain = str_replace("http://www.","",$base);
$cookiedomain = str_replace("https://www.","",$cookiedomain);
$cookiedomain = str_replace("www.","",$cookiedomain);

$url = $base . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on'){
    $mydomain = 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
} else {
    $mydomain = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
}

// Open the cURL session
$curlSession = curl_init();

curl_setopt ($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($curlSession, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    curl_setopt ($curlSession, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt ($curlSession, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);
}

curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,30);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
curl_setopt ($curlSession, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt ($curlSession, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);

//handle other cookies cookies
foreach($_COOKIE as $k=>$v){
    if(is_array($v)){
        $v = serialize($v);
    }
    curl_setopt($curlSession,CURLOPT_COOKIE,"$k=$v; domain=.$cookiedomain ; path=/");
}

//Send the request and store the result in an array
$response = curl_exec ($curlSession);

// Check that a connection was made
if (curl_error($curlSession)){
    // If it wasn't...
    print curl_error($curlSession);
} else {

    //clean duplicate header that seems to appear on fastcgi with output buffer on some servers!!
    $response = str_replace("HTTP/1.1 100 Continue\r\n\r\n","",$response);

    $ar = explode("\r\n\r\n", $response, 2);

    $header = $ar[0];
    $body = $ar[1];

    //handle headers - simply re-outputing them
    $header_ar = split(chr(10),$header);
    foreach($header_ar as $k=>$v){
        if(!preg_match("/^Transfer-Encoding/",$v)){
            $v = str_replace($base,$mydomain,$v); //header rewrite if needed
            header(trim($v));
        }
    }

    //rewrite all hard coded urls to ensure the links still work!
    $body = str_replace($base,$mydomain,$body);

    #print $body;
    echo file_get_contents($_POST['address']);

}

curl_close ($curlSession);

?>
```

If I submit the test form on the index.php file I get the data no problem, but when running the same request through Ajax I get a 404. Is anybody able to show me the error of my ways?

Comment: Try providing an absolute URL instead of `proxy.php`. Let me know how that works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried this but when viewing the request in Chrome's console it's looking at the correct URL for proxy.php which is what has me so confused.

Comment: In your section of code where you define $url = $base . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], the 'REQUEST_URI' is simply 'proxy.php' when you initiate it via ajax call. I suggest you log the $url on the php side so you can see what it's being set to. You could pass the URL you need in an 'address' property in the data object and use that instead of the request_uri

Comment: Thanks for the response Walker - it looks like we're on to something! The logged URL is http://www.bungie.net/destiny/proxy.php. If I change the line $url = $base . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; to $url = $base . $_POST['address']; then it logs the correct URL but now I'm getting a 405 error - method not allowed?